# How to generate HTML from XML schema (XSD)

Tags: html, xml, xsd, schema, code-generation

How can we generate the HTML from XML schema (XSD). Is there any open source java project to take care of HTML generation. Once we read the schema can we check about attribute properties like read-only or Numeric.

Thanks 
Rohit

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking about getting a hyperlinked HTML rendition of the schema document, Michael Sperberg-McQueen has produced a stylesheet announced here:

http://lists.xml.org/archives/xml-dev/201102/msg00064.html

It works best when the schema is written in a literate style, with plenty of explanation in xsd:annotation elements.

Comment: Thanks Michael !! I am going through the link you have provided. Will get back to you if I found some issue.